# Put Table View inside Container View in swift 3

Tags: uitableview, swift3, uicontainerview

I have 2 segmented control button.  "Apple" and "Orange" segmented button.
I put table view in it and when user taps on "Apple", the Apple Table View will appear.

I put another "Container" view in it (named: "Orange Container view")and when user taps on "Orange" tab, it will show up. 

Container View has child view controller. So, I put "Table View" named Orange TableView in child view controller. 
The problem is that
when I click on "Apple" tab, Apple Table View rows appear immediately but Orange Table View won't show immediately when I click on Orange tab.

 
How can I reload the table from child view controller to show up immediately when I tap on "Orange" tab.
I tried "Dispatch" method. I don't know how to write table reload code for child view controller.

**[UPDATE: Solved Problem]**
I add following codes in Parent view controller.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(loadList), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)


func loadList(){
    //load data here
    self.OrangeContainerView.reloadInputViews()
}
```

I put following codes in child view controller.

```
 NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

Add Action on segment control from storyboard to this method

```
@IBAction func segmentChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    let orageViewController = self.childViewControllers[sender.selectedSegmentIndex] as! OrageViewController
        orageViewController.updateTable()

}
```

Now updateTable() is the method in ur child view controller(OrageViewController)
In OrageViewController

```
func updateTable(){

 yourTableView.reloadData()

}
```